# Php web application with java desktop application for a POS?

Tags: java, php, mysql

I have to develop a POS software, I was going to develop it in php with mysql, but, I'm worried about what happens if we have internet problems, so, I was thinking on use a desktop java application for the store, with its own local data base, and daily update a remote data base; besides, I would have a php page to get information about sales, storage, etc, but I'm not sure if this is a good approach, or even if is possible. Should I keep going with this approach, or is best to do all in the same language?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by have internet problems. Internet problems  generally affect your entire computer not just php.

Comment: Its definitely possible, and I don't think the approach is bad.  I would opt for having it be in live-mode by default, and falling back to a "stand-alone" if connectivity were an issue, but that's just my opinion.  There is nothing wrong with mixing languages in an end-to-end solution, and in fact that is usually the case anyhow.

Comment: @ns47731 I know that, I mean that if I my internet connection fails,  I won't be able to access my system web page.